What is the definition of morality in Judaism
How does Judaism define morality?
Is it simply the word of God without further explanation?
Is there some mantra that could summarize Judaism's stance on morality?

Why assume Judaism has an official definition of some English word?

Being that this is an english language site i am using the english word for the equivalent of a set of principles which govern what is good and bad

https://sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp012.htm

Another suggestion: https://sacred-texts.com/jud/wott/wott08.htm. Personal Morality in the Talmud

If there's a Lashon Hakodesh word for morality, then that's your answer. If there isn't, then that's your answer, or at least the start of one :)

@Shababnik Great! "set of principles which govern what is good and bad" is your answer then. What do you need us for?

Judaism holds both ends of the stick: on the one hand, the tradition holds that all morality is God-dictated, immutable, and eternal, on the other hand, the same tradition teaches that God let Jewish sages change morals as they please. Practically, in all Jewish Diaspora, Jewish morality is practically indistinguishable from that of their hosts.

For example, in places where slavery is moral, it is also moral with the Jews, where it is immoral, Jews are the first to abolish it. Where domestic violence is moral, it is also moral with the Jews, where women's equality is moral rabbis let their women work and vote.

The Torah says:

Be sure to keep the commandments, decrees, and laws that the Lord your God has enjoined upon you.  Do what is right and good in the sight of the Lord, so that it may go well with you. [Deut. 6:17-18]

Why the apparent repetition?  Because you must sometimes go beyond what is strictly commanded in the Torah to “do what is right and good”. That's where morality comes in.  The Ramban explains:

Even regarding what God did not command, pay attention to do what is good and right in God's eyes, because God loves goodness and righteousness. And it is important because it is impossible to mention in the Torah what should be everyone's conduct with their neighbors and friends, in business, etc., in every single case.


The Torah mentions many relevant laws explicitly, such as:
“Do not gossip” [Leviticus 19:16];
“You shall not take vengeance or bear a grudge” [Leviticus 19:18];
“You shall not stand idly by the blood of your neighbor” [Leviticus 19:16];
“You shall not insult the deaf” [Leviticus 19:14];
“You shall rise before the aged” [Leviticus 19:32]; etc.;
then goes on to state in a general way that in all matters one should do what is good and right, compromise and go beyond the strict requirement of the law … One should behave in this manner to be worthy of being called “good and upright.”

